# Getting access to a UITableViewCell row that is currently not showing

Tags: iphone, uitableview

Is there a way to get access to a UITableViewCell that is not currently on screen?  I'm trying to update rows that are currently not in view.  I am using this collapsable/expandable rows for a UITableView in one of Apple's example codes.  I use this:

```
for (NSInteger row = 0; row < totalRows; row++) {
    NSIndexPath *path = [NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:row inSection:section];
    OrderTableViewCell *cell = (OrderTableViewCell *)[_tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:path];
    cell.CheckmarkButton.selected = YES;
    cell.Symbol.isSelected = YES;
}
```

My totalRows is correct in that I get the number of rows from the TableView.  So I thought I could use that, loop through all the rows, and set some values.  However, if I check the state of the rows, the ones that are currently on screen have values and I can change them, but the ones off screen are null and cannot be set.  Is there a way I can get around this?  Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Depending on what you want to update you could just update the ith entry in a backing collection.

For example you could have a collection that stores bools corresponding to CheckmarkButton selected. In your loop you could set `myArray[row] = YES`. In `cellForRowAtIndexPath` you can do `cell.CheckmarkButton.selected = myArray[indexPath.row]`.

If you want to maintain multiple items for each cell then `myArray` in the above example could contain instances of an object that holds values relevant to the ith cell.

Answer (score 0):

Well why do you have to update a cell like that... If the cell is out of view, to save memory the system unloads it, and since its not in the view there is no need for you to update the cell directly, rather you should have the state be reflected in such way that when cellForRowIndexPath is called by the table view to load the cell the desired look is shown... The only reason youd want to do what you are doing is if the cell is showing and you need to update the cell, for the user... Even then you can still set your state and call the reloadRowsAtIndexPaths instead of manipulating the cell directly... Hope that helps

Comment: I'm trying to do a check all mechanism to check all the selected rows.  That was just my thought process was to get the row to set a property on the row so when it is displayed, it will reflect a checkmark.  Would you use what MrMusic has recommended.

Comment: yes, what mrmusic has recommeneded is the way to go..its what I explain here but he has a more concrete example